# Bind multiple tables from Stored procedure to MVC model using EF DB first

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My store procedure will return multiple result sets. How can I bind them to my Model using EF db first approach?

My Models

```
 public class SearchCriteriaResults
    {
        [Key]
        public string RecordID { get; set; }
        public int? SNO { get; set; }
        public int? CountyCode { get; set; }
        public string CountyName { get; set; }
}
public class Locations
    {
        //Locations
        public byte section { get; set; }
        public byte township { get; set; }
        public byte range { get; set; }
}
```

Every RecordID will contain multiple records in Locations.

My code for SP

```
public List<SearchCriteriaResults> GetRecordDetailsbyID(string RecID)
    {
        List<SearchCriteriaResults> strResult = new List<SearchCriteriaResults>();
        try
        {
            strResult = objVCHEntities.ExecuteStoreQuery<SearchCriteriaResults>          ("[GetRecordDetailsbyID] @RecID={0}", RecID).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return strResult;
    }
```

I always get only 1 record binded to `SearchCriteriaResults` from SP.
My SP Query

```
select rd.RecordID,bookType,grantee,grantor from Record rd where rd.RecordID = '12345' 
select section from Location where RecordID = '12345'
```

In the above query I can use join also, but how to bind to my Model classes?